LWC dispatch event response
I have a child LWC inside of an Aura component.
This is the child LWC component builds up the CustomEvent:

this is the parent Aura component that reads the event:

I was expecting to read the response like this (this came from ChatGPT):
handleAssignedToLookupSearch(event) { 
const {searchTerm, rawSearchTerm, selectedIds} = event.detail; 
console.log('Search Term:', searchTerm); 
console.log('Raw Search Term:', rawSearchTerm); 
console.log('Selected IDs:', selectedIds); }

But it doesnt work since "event" is undefined
if I JSON.stringfy the response, I get this:
{"Jv":"search","Uf":{},"Sp":{"searchTerm":"test","rawSearchTerm":"test","selectedIds":[]},"target":null,"currentTarget":null}

So the answer would need to be "event.Sp.searchTerm" which works fine.
But the question is why the response coming on this Sp object? Why isnt event.searchTerm?
Thanks in advance!
